# Appium server automatically quit session while waiting

Tags: java, appium

I am doing automation with Appium on Android platform. Due to some reason, I need to wait for some time during the test. However, Appium automatically quit session if it does not receive commands in around 4 seconds. Can anyone help me tell me how to make Appium not quit my driver.

I have tried add "newCommandTimeout" to capability, but it does not work.

```
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 120000);
```

Appium version: v1.9.1

Here are appium logs while session is quiting:

```
[W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["d9a0e702-f477-439b-8502-aa9d3c93737f"]
[BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1548332599830 (20:23:19 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time))
[Appium] Removing session d9a0e702-f477-439b-8502-aa9d3c93737f from our master session list
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
```

**Jan 29 2019 UPDATE:**

As suggested by most people, I have tried set 300 to newCommandTimeout

```
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 300);
```

Session is still quiting. I use Thread.sleep(5000) to make script wait. Here are logs for creating sessions and closing sessions in Appium. Timestamp is added. It looks like sessions are closed automatically after 10 seconds waiting.

```
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v4.1.1) session
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium] Capabilities:
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium]   platform: ANDROID
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium]   platformName: android
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium]   appActivity: *****
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium]   appPackage: *****
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium]   deviceName: *****
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium]   language: en
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium]   locale: US
[2019-01-29 01:03:51][Appium]   newCommandTimeout: 300
<SOME LOGS OMITTED>
[2019-01-29 01:04:10][HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 18650 ms - 913
[2019-01-29 01:04:10][HTTP] 
[2019-01-29 01:04:10][HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/f1dbcd92-fa13-4fc7-a9fd-e6a82b55f9e7
[2019-01-29 01:04:10][HTTP] {}
[2019-01-29 01:04:10][HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f1dbcd92-fa13-4fc7-a9fd-e6a82b55f9e7 200 5 ms - 845
[2019-01-29 01:04:10][HTTP] 
[2019-01-29 01:04:10][HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/f1dbcd92-fa13-4fc7-a9fd-e6a82b55f9e7
[2019-01-29 01:04:10][HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f1dbcd92-fa13-4fc7-a9fd-e6a82b55f9e7 200 3 ms - 845
[2019-01-29 01:04:10][HTTP] 
[2019-01-29 01:04:20][HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/f1dbcd92-fa13-4fc7-a9fd-e6a82b55f9e7
[2019-01-29 01:04:20][HTTP] {}
[2019-01-29 01:04:20][W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["f1dbcd92-fa13-4fc7-a9fd-e6a82b55f9e7"]
[2019-01-29 01:04:20][BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1548738260177 (13:04:20 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time))
[2019-01-29 01:04:20][Appium] Removing session f1dbcd92-fa13-4fc7-a9fd-e6a82b55f9e7 from our master session list
[2019-01-29 01:04:20][AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
```

**Jan 29 2019 UPDATE II:**
After a couple of trial & error, I found the root cause is the driver.currentActivity() after sleep. I am getting this Exception. Because our framework caught this, it sent the shut down signal to Appium.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_192'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:233)
```

This Exception only happens when I do driver.currentActivity() after wait for 10 seconds. My goal is to let script wait until it sees another activity. Currently my workaround is this:

```
int counter = 0;
while(oDriver.currentActivity().contains("someActivity")) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    counter++;
    if ( counter >= 10 ) break;
}
if (oDriver.currentActivity().contains("someActivity"))
    System.out.println("Reached");
```

Comment: Are you connecting directly to Appium node, or are you using Selenium grid?

Comment: Also do you have deviceReadyTimeout capability defined?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the timeout setting is in seconds, not milliseconds.  I'm using 300 in my code and it works fine: `capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 300);` Perhaps it's ignoring your parameter because the value it too high?  Also, what's in the log BEFORE it deletes the session?

Comment: You should use  capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 300). it will waitt for 5 minutes even if no commands triggered. You have given very long value that is why it is not working i guess. I have been using this

Comment: @Angusiasty. I am connecting to Appium node directly. I guess deviceReadyTimeout is for waiting the session to be setup. I didnt specify it so the default value should be 30 seconds

Comment: Thanks @Bill Hileman. I have tried set 300 for newCommandTimeout, but doesnt work, updated logs are available.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh Chaudhary. I have tried set 300 for newCommandTimeout, but doesnt work, updated logs are available.

Comment: Can you please add the script here what you are trying to run. Issue seems to be with code

Comment: @Rajesh Chaudhary, found the root cause is some weird Exception thrown by driver.currentActivity().

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct answer to this question.

```
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 300);
```

Thanks @Rajesh Chaudhary.

I will create a separate question regarding exceptions encountered during driver.currentActivity().

Answer (score 0):

If anyone arrives here and is having the same issue but using javascript like me below is my solution. I am using appium from a nodejs script. I am using the **webdriverio** package on version **7.31.1** to automate testing on a physical **Android** device that is usb tethered.

```js
{
  platformName: 'Android',
  'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
  'appium:deviceName': 'Android',
  'appium:appPackage': 'appPackage',
  'appium:appActivity': 'appActivity',
  'appium:newCommandTimeout': 120000
}
```

Adding the last property **'appium:newCommandTimeout': 120000** fixed for me.

Here is a setup script I use:

```js
import {
  remote
} from 'webdriverio'
/**
 * Handles options configuration for the webdriver remote instance.
 * @param {string} appPackage - The package name. ex: someapp.android.
 * @param {string} appActivity - The first activity to launch. ex: com.yadaa.ydaa
 * @param {string | undefined} udid - The unique id of the target device. Can be left off if only one device.
 * @returns {Promise<WebdriverIO.Browser>} - Promise containing the webdriver browser object aka driver.
 */
export const appiumSetup = async(appPackage, appActivity, udid) => {
  let port = 4723
  if (process?.env?.APPIUM_PORT) {
    const portNumber = parseInt(process.env.APPIUM_PORT, 10)
    if (!isNaN(portNumber)) {
      port = portNumber
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Invalid APPIUM_PORT: ${process.env.APPIUM_PORT}. Falling back to default port: ${port}`
      )
    }
  }
  return await remote({
    hostname: process.env.APPIUM_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: port || 4723,
    logLevel: 'info',
    capabilities: !udid ?
      {
        platformName: 'Android',
        'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
        'appium:deviceName': 'Android',
        'appium:appPackage': appPackage,
        'appium:appActivity': appActivity,
        'appium:newCommandTimeout': 120000
      } :
      {
        platformName: 'Android',
        'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
        'appium:deviceName': 'Android',
        'appium:appPackage': appPackage,
        'appium:appActivity': appActivity,
        'appium:newCommandTimeout': 120000,
        'appium:udid': udid
      }
  })
}
```

Then to use:

```js
import {
  appiumSetup
} from 'appiumSetup.js'

async someFuncName() {
  const driver = await appiumSetup(
    'com.samsung.android.messaging',
    'com.android.mms.ui.ConversationCompose'
  )
}
```