# Appium driver.currentActivity() cause java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I am automating android using Appium against real devices. I observed that if my script wait for some time, e.g. 10 seconds, then I call driver.currentActivity(). This will cause following Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_192'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:233)
....
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

I have tried to google it, but seems no open issue for this. Can anyone suggest what could be wrong? Here is automation script:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DesiredCapabilities oMobileCapability = new DesiredCapabilities();

        oMobileCapability.setCapability("deviceName", "****");
        oMobileCapability.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        oMobileCapability.setCapability("platform", "Android");
        oMobileCapability.setCapability("appPackage", "****");
        oMobileCapability.setCapability("appActivity", "****");
        oMobileCapability.setCapability("language", "en");
        oMobileCapability.setCapability("locale", "US");
        oMobileCapability.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 300);

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> oDriver;
        oDriver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL ("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), oMobileCapability);

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Wait Complete!");

        System.out.println(oDriver.currentActivity());

        oDriver.quit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I can see "Wait Complete!", then Exception happens. I am connecting to local Appium node directly.

```
Appium: v1.9.1
Java: 8
java-client: 6.0.0
```

**Feb 2 UPDATE**
This issue was found during trouble shooting this issue:
[Appium server automatically quit session while waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346747/appium-server-automatically-quit-session-while-waiting)

Comment: What is visible on the device or emulator?  Does the application load and go to the activity specified?

Comment: @Bill Hileman, this issue is for device. Until now I have tried a few devices, all behaves same.

Comment: You only answered one of my two questions.  Is the device responding to the script at least to the point of starting the activity?  Is the app even starting at all on the device?  I'm trying to determine if you're getting a successful connection.

Comment: @BillHileman, yes I am pretty sure that it connects well. The script here is just to show this issue. If I replace currentActivity() with findElementsById(...) , the script performs well.